# mat-expansion-panel. trying to show 2 columns of iterated object, but only 1st iteration is visible when using flexLayout="row"

Tags: angular, angular-flex-layout, mat-expansion-panel

I'm having a strange error when trying to display 2 columns of an object. The expansion panel displays fine, though it doesn't fill the container like  I want it to, but only the first item of the object displays. I know I'm getting the object in console log. I think it's a formatting issue. Any ideas?

```
    <ng-container *ngIf="configurations$ | async as configurations" hideToggle>
    <mat-expansion-panel *ngFor="let item of configurations | keyvalue">
      <mat-expansion-panel-header>
        <div >
<!--          <pre>{{configurations | json}}</pre>-->
          <div fxFlexFill fxLayout="row" >
            <mat-panel-title fxFlex="30%">
              Name of Vaccine: {{item.key}}
            </mat-panel-title>
            <mat-panel-title fxFlex="70%">
              Description: {{item.value.description}}
            </mat-panel-title>
          </div>
        </div>
      </mat-expansion-panel-header>
      <p>This is the primary content of the panel.</p>
  </mat-expansion-panel>
    <mat-expansion-panel (opened)="panelOpenState = true"
                         (closed)="panelOpenState = false">
    </mat-expansion-panel>
</ng-container>
  </mat-accordion>
</div>
```

ts file

```
import {Component, OnInit, ChangeDetectionStrategy, OnDestroy, ViewChild} from '@angular/core';
import {AngularFirestore} from "@angular/fire/firestore";
import {catchError, map, tap} from "rxjs/operators";
import {of} from "rxjs";
import {MatAccordion} from "@angular/material/expansion";
import {FlexLayoutModule} from "@angular/flex-layout";

@Component({
  templateUrl: './vaccine-codes.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./vaccine-codes.component.scss'],
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
export class VaccineCodesComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  @ViewChild(MatAccordion) accordion: MatAccordion;

  panelOpenState = false;
    configurations$ = this.afs.collection<Vaccine[]>('configurations').doc('CVXCODES').valueChanges()
    .pipe(tap(console.log));
  dtp$ = this.configurations$.pipe(map((data: Vaccine[]) => {
    data?.find((v: Vaccine) => v.Codes?.includes('dtp'))
  }),
    catchError(err => {
      console.error("dtp$", err);
      return of([]);
    }));

  constructor(private afs: AngularFirestore) {

  }

    ngOnInit(): void {

  }
  ngOnDestroy() {
  }
  async getConf() {
    try {
      const configurations = await this.afs.collection<Configuration>('configurations').doc('CVXCODES').get().toPromise();
    } catch (e) {
      console.error("getConf error", e)
    }
  }

}

export interface Configuration {
  ChpPrefix: string;
  Vaccines: { [key: string]: Vaccine[] };
  description: string;

}

export interface Vaccine {
  Codes: string[] | null;
}
```

css

```
.container {
  min-width: 500px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  align-items: baseline;

}

.align {
  justify-content: space-between;

}

.mat-expansion-panel-header {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}
```

I know I have a lot to learn especially CSS, but this project has a deadline, so I'm hoping for some quick inspiration.

Answer (score 0):

the problem was that I put the ngFor in the wrong place. I've adjusted the code.